# Symfony: oneToOne not getting data using doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

When I am using oneToOne using doctrine I got problem with fetching data from StockCategories Entity and also StockTax Entity. The main entity in which I got implemented oneToOne is StockLevels. The problem is that I have got e.g. in table stock_categories records (1, computers, Computers, 1) and (1, phones, Phones, 1). I would like to get them as choice type when I am adding something new to stock_levels. Here you got screen (http://i44.tinypic.com/307yrty.jpg) from it and below my files.

```
// Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockLevels

/**
 * @var \Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockTax
 */
private $stocktax;


/**
 * Set stocktax
 *
 * @param \Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockTax $stocktax
 * @return StockLevels
 */
public function setStocktax(\Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockTax $stocktax = null)
{
    $this->stocktax = $stocktax;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get stocktax
 *
 * @return \Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockTax 
 */
public function getStocktax()
{
    return $this->stocktax;
}
/**
 * @var \Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockCategories
 */
private $stockcategories;


/**
 * Set stockcategories
 *
 * @param \Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockCategories $stockcategories
 * @return StockLevels
 */
public function setStockcategories(\Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockCategories $stockcategories = null)
{
    $this->stockcategories = $stockcategories;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get stockcategories
 *
 * @return \Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockCategories 
 */
public function getStockcategories()
{
    return $this->stockcategories;
}

------------------------------------------------------------
// Application\StockBundle\Form\Type\StockCategoriesType

namespace Application\StockBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class StockCategoriesType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockCategories',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'stockcategories';
    }
}
--------------------------------------------
// Application\StockBundle\Admin\StockLevelsView
 /**
 * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $formMapper
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
$this->user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

    $formMapper
        ->with('General')
            ->add('sku', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('name', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('description', null, array('required' => false))
            ->add('stockcategories' , new StockCategoriesType())
            ->add('pkwiu' , 'choice', array('choices' => array(1 => 'pkwiu1', 2 => 'pkwiu2')))
            ->add('type' , 'choice', array('choices' => array(1 => 'Produkt', 2 => 'Usługa')))
            ->add('status' , 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
            ->add('lastmodified_date' , 'hidden', array('data' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')))
            ->add('lastmodified_user_id' , 'hidden', array('data' => $this->user->getId()))
        ->end()
        ->with('Barcode')
            ->add('barcode', null, array('required' => false))
        ->end()
        ->with('Price')
            ->add('price', 'number', array('required' => true))
            ->add('price_old', 'number', array('required' => false))
            ->add('stocktax' , new StockTaxType())
            ->add('currency' , 'hidden', array('data' => 'PLN'))
        ->end()
        ->with('Warehouse')
            ->add('quantity', 'number', array('required' => true))
            ->add('reorder_level', 'number', array('required' => false))
        ->end()
        ->with('Extra')
            ->add('unit', 'choice', array('choices' => array(1 => 'szt', 2 => 'waga')))
            ->add('weight', 'number', array('required' => false))
        ->end()
    ;

    if(!$this->getSubject()->getId()) $formMapper->with('General')
            ->add('created_date', 'hidden', array('data' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')))
            ->add('created_user_id' , 'hidden', array('data' => $this->user->getId()));
}
```

In StockLevels.orm.yml I got:

```
oneToOne:
  stocktax:
    targetEntity: StockTax
    joinColumn:
      name: tax_id
      referencedColumnName: id
  stockcategories:
    targetEntity: StockCategories
    joinColumn:
      name: category_id
      referencedColumnName: id
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I believe you need to use the `joinColumn` declaration on only one of the entities, but not both.

Comment: It is not that as when I removed oneToOne for stocktax it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "Adam-E" from post's comment is correct, however, if order to build bidirectional relationship you need to define `owning` and `inverse` side.

Also, I am a bit unclear about your entities' structure, so please tell if I made some mistake. The important part is to define both `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` as described in official docs: [Bidirectional OneToOne](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional)

**StockLevels.orm.yml:**

```
oneToOne:
  stocktax:
    targetEntity: StockTax
    mappedBy: stockcategories
    joinColumn:
      tax_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
```

**StockTax.orm.yml**

```
oneToOne:
    stockcategories:
        targetEntity: StockLevels
        inversedBy: stocktax
```

Comment: Thanks @jperovic but it is not that. The strange thing is this that when I will use ->add('categories', 'entity', array(class' => 'Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockCategories','property' => 'name', 'multiple' => true,)) straight in configureFormFields then it works, but if I want to use buildForm it doesn't